# How do i parse data file with similar structure to INI using python?

Tags: python, pandas, database, parsing, text-parsing

i have a file containing large data in the following format :

```
[metadata]      
metadata1   metadata2 metadata3
[data]      
label1   label2    label3
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
...
```

I am trying to load the data section to process in my python script as a pandas dataframe.

What i've tried so far is loading the file in excel and saving it as a sheet then loading in into a dataframe using  `pandas.read_excel()` but this is not a practical solution as you can imagine.

I would appreciate help on this subject and thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it following way: open file for reading, consume lines until `[data]` is found, give it to `pandas.read_csv` specyfing whitespaces as separator. Let `file.txt` content

```
[metadata]      
metadata1   metadata2 metadata3
[data]      
label1   label2    label3
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

then

```
import pandas as pd
f = open("file.txt", "r")
while(next(f).strip()!='[data]'):
    pass
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+')
f.close()
print(df)
```

output

```
   label1  label2  label3
0       0       0       0
1       0       0       0
2       0       0       0
```

Explanation: tail of file might be considered as csv file with whitespaces as separator, by consuming lines up to `[data]` I am seeking to point so what follows is legal csv, then use `pandas.read_csv` function. Note that if number of lines before line with labels is known you might just exploit `pandas.read_csv`'s `skiprows`.